# Modifying the default MVC app to show additional properties

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to modify the default MVC project so that instead of showing a username, I can display their full name.  Eg, the default app shows

```
Hello <username>!   Log off
```

I added a new property **FullName** to the **ApplicationUser** class.  The code that shows the name currently is:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Hello " + User.Identity.GetUserName() + "!", "Manage", "Account", routeValues:=Nothing, htmlAttributes:=New With {.title = "Manage"})
```

So how can I get lookup that value from the ApplicationUser class and display it here?  Additionally, is there a way to cache this?  It seems like a waste to perform a lookup for every request.

I also might want to show their email address instead, so I definitely need to use a new property.

Answer (score 1):

I generally like to serialize a user object in the FormsAuthentication cookie when they login and then create a class inheriting from IPrincipal so that my views can read the de-serialized object:

```
public interface IUserPrincipal : IPrincipal
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string FirstName { get; set; }
    string LastName { get; set; }
    string Username { get; set; }
}

public class UserPrincipal : IUserPrincipal
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }

    public IIdentity Identity { get; private set; }

    public UserPrincipal(string Username)
    {
        this.Identity = new GenericIdentity(Username);
    }
}

public class UserPrincipalPoco
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Username { get; set; }
}
```

and then when authenticating:

```
public ActionResult Login(LoginViewModel vm, string ReturnUrl)
{
    // Check for valid authentication
    if (_authenticationService.Authenticate(vm.Username, vm.Password))
    {
        // Add forms authentication cookie
        Response.Cookies.Add(GetFormsAuthenticationCookie(vm.Username));

        // Redirect after authentication
    }    

    // Failed authentication, redirect to unauthorized
}  

private HttpCookie GetFormsAuthenticationCookie(string Username)
{
    var user = _userService.GetUserByUsername(Username);

    UserPrincipalPoco pocoModel = new UserPrincipalPoco();
    pocoModel.Id = user.Id.Value;
    pocoModel.FirstName = user.FirstName;
    pocoModel.LastName = user.LastName;
    pocoModel.Username = Username;

    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

    string userData = serializer.Serialize(pocoModel);

    FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
        1,
        Username,
        DateTime.Now,
        DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(15),
        false,
        userData);

    string encryptedTicket = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(authTicket);

    return new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, encryptedTicket);
}
```

and then in global.asax.cs:

```
    protected void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpCookie authCookie = Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName];

        if (authCookie != null)
        {
            FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);

            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

            UserPrincipalPoco serializeModel = serializer.Deserialize<UserPrincipalPoco>(authTicket.UserData);

            UserPrincipal newUser = new UserPrincipal(authTicket.Name);
            newUser.Id = serializeModel.Id;
            newUser.FirstName = serializeModel.FirstName;
            newUser.LastName = serializeModel.LastName;
            newUser.Username = serializeModel.Username;

            HttpContext.Current.User = newUser;
        }
    }
```

Now you need to create a BaseViewPage that inherits from WebViewPage to tell your views to use your UserPrincipal object:

```
    public abstract class BaseViewPage : WebViewPage
{
    public virtual new UserPrincipal User
    {
        get { return base.User as UserPrincipal; }
    }
}

public abstract class BaseViewPage<TModel> : WebViewPage<TModel>
{
    public virtual new UserPrincipal User
    {
        get { return base.User as UserPrincipal; }
    }
}
```

and in your Web.config tell your views to always use this BaseViewPage:

```
<pages pageBaseType="MyNameSpace.Views.BaseViewPage">
```

Now in my views I can access the user like:

```
@User.Username
```

or

```
@User.FirstName @User.LastName
```

Comment: I tried pasting this into the default MVC app and I've two issues.  The first is that @User.FirstName (or any of the properties) are not available in the View.  The second is, when I click "logoff" the logged in username is still appearing.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that you need to create a BaseViewPage and tell your Web.config to always use that type of View so that you can access your  UserPrincipal object. I've edited the answer above. Also, you will still need to check @if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) and make sure you are logging out via FormsAuthentication.SignOut();

Answer (score -1):

few ways you can do it.

if the application is not too big, you may cache the user models that log in for a specific period of time so you can pull the entire user info based on the username.

you may save a list if info in User.Identity, including username, firstname, last name etc, separating them with a comma or etc.

a bad way: every time you need the extra info, hit the database and get them.

my opinion: cache the recent users who have been logged in for a specific amount of time. you will be able to create slick solutions using cashing. let me know if you need info.